# Im not able to display the items in my cart angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

can anyone look into this code and explain why I'm not able to display the items in my cart. Its a simple shopping cart where I display a list of products from array and when i click on each item details are displayed with add to cart option, but when i click on items in my cart it is not showing the items added?

here is my link to plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/oo05d6H6AxuJGXBAUQvr?p=preview

This is my script.js

```
// Code goes here



var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.controller('mobileController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Iphone',
    price: 70000,
    rating: '*****',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/hfMaGTN.png'
  }, {
    name: 'Oneplus',
    price: 60000,
    rating: '****',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/sBcs5ZE.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Samsung',
    price: 50000,
    rating: '***',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/8Bexxbf.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Sony',
    price: 40000,
    rating: '***',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/0c7PcX8.png'
  }, {
    name: 'Moto',
    price: 20000,
    rating: '****',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/HyWR1VE.png'
  }];
});

app.service("cartService", [function(){

  var cart = [];

  function getCart(){
    console.log(cart);
    return cart;
  }

  function addToCart(item){
    cart.push(item);
    console.log(cart);
  }

  return {
    getCart: getCart,
    addToCart: addToCart
  };

}]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/store", {
templateUrl : "store.html",

 })

 .when('/item/:itemName', {
      templateUrl: 'details.html',
      controller: 'ItemCtrl'
    })
    .when("/cart", {
      templateUrl: 'cartdetails.html',
      controller: 'cartCtrl'
    });
});

app.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'cartService',
  function($scope, $routeParams, cartService) {
    $scope.item = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      if (item.name == $routeParams.itemName) {
        $scope.item.itemName = item.name;
        $scope.item.itemPrice = item.price;
        $scope.item.itemRating = item.rating;
        $scope.item.itemImage = item.image;
      }
    });

    $scope.addProduct = function(item){
      console.log(item);
      cartService.addToCart(item);
    };
  }
]);
app.controller('cartCtrl', ['$scope','cartService',
  function($scope,cartService) {
    $scope.name="sasiree";

    var cartItems=cartService.getCart();



  }
]);
```

Comment: Because you didn't bind it.   $scope.cartItems=cartService.getCart();  instead of   var cartItems=cartService.getCart();

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controller('cartCtrl', ['$scope','cartService',
  function($scope,cartService) {
    $scope.name="sasiree";

    $scope.cartItems=cartService.getCart();



  }
]);
```

You need to put `$scope` to use it in the html!

Comment: thank you! it worked, can I also do something so that when user clicks add to cart button something like added successfully should pop up?

Comment: Can U please accept the answer. So can be considered closed. Click on the right tick below the downarrow.

Comment: And yes you can do that too. U can just `alert(item.name+" added successfully")` under `add product`